# Upwork app closes my user session

Tags: 16.04

After recent update of my Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit) when I start Upwork app I'm simply **logged out** from **Ubuntu** and I'm redirected to Login screen. 
After I log in everything is ok, but Upwork app is still not working.